# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Crash when displaying AdWhirl ad on iPhone

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, adwhirl

I am using AdWhirl in my app and got a suspicious crash mid-game.
It appears to crash in the animationDidStop:finished: function which I didn't create.
Could this be a bug in AdWhirl?

I can't find this file referenced in the log:

```
(MMHTMLAdView.m:123)
```

This is the log:

```
Date/Time:       2010-10-21 09:54:14.861 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000015
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   LoopMaster Lite                 0x000b7e38 -[MMHTMLAdView animationDidStop:finished:] (MMHTMLAdView.m:123)
2   QuartzCore                      0x0002d8c2 run_animation_callbacks(double, void*) + 286
3   QuartzCore                      0x0002d764 CA::timer_callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 116
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000567f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000562a6 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 854
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0002779e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
9   GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
10  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
11  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
12  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
13  LoopMaster Lite                 0x000022b0 main (main.m:14)
14  LoopMaster Lite                 0x00002280 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6b6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d65bc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d675c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a67a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791d4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002e1a2 _pthread_cond_wait + 742
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000346c2 pthread_cond_timedwait + 30
3   WebCore                         0x00057ca0 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 412
4   WebCore                         0x00057af8 WebThreadCallDelegate + 12
5   WebKit                          0x00024c54 CallFrameLoadDelegate(objc_object* (*)(objc_object*, objc_selector*, ...), WebView*, objc_selector*, objc_object*) + 292
6   WebKit                          0x0000bff0 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDidFinishLoad() + 108
7   WebCore                         0x00080aa4 WebCore::FrameLoader::checkLoadCompleteForThisFrame() + 684
8   WebCore                         0x0008078e WebCore::FrameLoader::recursiveCheckLoadComplete() + 238
9   WebCore                         0x000b1632 WebCore::FrameLoader::checkLoadComplete() + 26
10  WebCore                         0x000b12d0 WebCore::DocumentLoader::removeSubresourceLoader(WebCore::ResourceLoader*) + 184
11  WebCore                         0x00494838 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFail(WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 84
12  WebCore                         0x001a6106 WebCore::ResourceLoader::didFail(WebCore::ResourceHandle*, WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 30
13  WebCore                         0x001a5f6c -[WebCoreResourceHandleAsDelegate connection:didFailWithError:] + 476
14  Foundation                      0x0003855e -[NSURLConnectionDelegateProxy connection:didFailWithError:] + 34
15  Foundation                      0x000381fe -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFail:] + 130
16  Foundation                      0x00038138 _NSURLConnectionDidFail + 80
17  CFNetwork                       0x000999bc URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFailWithError(__CFError*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 416
18  CFNetwork                       0x00004b44 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 208
19  CFNetwork                       0x00004dc6 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 850
20  CFNetwork                       0x000049c4 URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 64
21  CFNetwork                       0x00004976 URLConnection::multiplexerClientPerform(RunLoopMultiplexer*) + 30
22  CFNetwork                       0x000048f4 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 120
23  CFNetwork                       0x00004872 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 2
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00055f1e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00027ba0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00027444 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
29  WebCore                         0x000024e2 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
30  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
31  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x0002d686 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025060 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0005edfc __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   LoopMaster Lite                 0x00048592 -[GSAsyncCommandManager gsCommandExecThreadMain:] (GSAsyncCommandManager.m:106)
7   Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   LoopMaster Lite                 0x00048592 -[GSAsyncCommandManager gsCommandExecThreadMain:] (GSAsyncCommandManager.m:106)
7   Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b551e _mdns_query_mDNSResponder + 526
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b5be8 _mdns_search + 996
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b68bc _mdns_addrinfo + 344
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b69d6 search_addrinfo + 74
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002bdc8 si_addrinfo + 928
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002ba16 si_list_call + 138
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b90e si_async_launchpad + 70
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b551e _mdns_query_mDNSResponder + 526
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b5be8 _mdns_search + 996
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b68bc _mdns_addrinfo + 344
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b69d6 search_addrinfo + 74
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002bdc8 si_addrinfo + 928
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002ba16 si_list_call + 138
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b90e si_async_launchpad + 70
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b551e _mdns_query_mDNSResponder + 526
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b5be8 _mdns_search + 996
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b68bc _mdns_addrinfo + 344
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b69d6 search_addrinfo + 74
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002bdc8 si_addrinfo + 928
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002ba16 si_list_call + 138
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b90e si_async_launchpad + 70
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 10:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b551e _mdns_query_mDNSResponder + 526
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b5b24 _mdns_search + 800
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b68bc _mdns_addrinfo + 344
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000b69d6 search_addrinfo + 74
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002bdc8 si_addrinfo + 928
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002ba16 si_list_call + 138
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b90e si_async_launchpad + 70
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 11:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0987c1a0    r1: 0x000ce940      r2: 0x09897d10      r3: 0x0000002c
    r4: 0x0000000d    r5: 0x00000001      r6: 0x0030a490      r7: 0x2fffeac8
    r8: 0x0030a550    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x098891a0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x000b9f21    sp: 0x2fffeab4      lr: 0x000b7e3f      pc: 0x3002d7d8
  cpsr: 0x200f0030
```

Comment: MMHTMLAdView.m:123 what happens there?

Comment: I can't find that file/reference for the life of me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had many problems with AdWhirl. My last version was ok, the Millennial ad was displayed fine but did not work well when transitioning to iAd. When I tried to make a new version then whenever a new Millennial ad is received the app crashes. After struggling for a while I dumped AdWhirl and wrote my own interface to put a couple of ad networks together and it works without a hitch. So the problem is in the Adwhirl api, not the ad network API.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I was looking for, but decided to dump AdWhirl in favor of AdMob.
All the roads to errors were going through uncharted AdWhirl territory so decided to let them figure it out...